# Group by with tuples in F#

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a list of  tupples like these :

```
[("A",12); ("A",10); ("B",1);  ("C",2); ("C",1)]
```

And I would like to do some kind of `groupby` how do I handle that?

In pseudocode-SQL it should look something like this :

```
SELECT fst(tpl), sum(lst(tpl)) FROM [TupplesInList] GROUP BY fst(tpl)
```

yielding

```
 [("A",22); ("B",1); ("C",3)]
```

I could make a  Dictionary and add the ints if the key exist, but I can hardly believe that would be the best solution in a language as expressive as F#.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One solution:

```
let tuples = [("A",12); ("A",10); ("B",1);  ("C",2); ("C",1)]
tuples 
|> Seq.groupBy fst 
|> Seq.map (fun (key, values) -> (key, values |> Seq.sumBy snd))
```

**Edit:** ...or without piping:

```
let tuples = [("A",12); ("A",10); ("B",1);  ("C",2); ("C",1)]
Seq.map (fun (key, group) -> key, Seq.sumBy snd group)
        (Seq.groupBy fst tuples)
```

Answer (score 16):

To expand on Johan's answer, I tend to do this sort thing a lot and so have made the following generalized function.

```
let group_fold key value folder acc seq =
    seq |> Seq.groupBy key 
        |> Seq.map (fun (key, seq) -> (key, seq |> Seq.map value |> Seq.fold folder acc))
```

Which works for your tuple case as seen below

```
let tuples = [("A",12); ("A",10); ("B",1);  ("C",2); ("C",1)]
   
let regular = group_fold fst snd (+) 0 tuples 
let piped = tuples  |> group_fold fst snd (+) 0
```

but will also work with other sequences like a list of strings:

```
let strings = ["A12"; "A10"; "B1";  "C2"; "C1"]

let regular = group_fold (fun (x : string) -> x.[0]) (fun (x : string) -> int x.[1..]) (+) 0 strings 
let piped = strings  |> group_fold (fun x -> x.[0]) (fun x -> int x.[1..]) (+) 0
```